# Is KairosDB on Cassandra used for metrics alone?

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb

I want to create real-time dashboard. My data reside on Cassandra. Is KairosDB on Cassandra used for Cassandra monitoring? It just used to collect Cassandra metrics alone? Are there any other tool / open source available to display Cassandra data on real-time dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

KairosDB is used for Cassandra metrics only. It has integration with Grafana. So it make easy for DevOps to view Cassandra metrics on the dashboard.